# Разбить массив на два, слева четные, справа нечетные, и при этом сохранить порядок элементов среди четных и среди нечетных

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Я знаю только как решать сдвигом, типа каждый чн элемент сдвигаем влево. Но этот алгоритм неэффективный . Подскажите идею или советы для эффективного решения.

**Пример:**

Дано : `3 5 4 7 2 6 9 8`
Ответ : `4 2 6 8  3 5 7 9`

Comment: Память дополнительная есть?

Answer (score 2):

```
std::stable_partition(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr),
        [](int x) { return !(x & 1); });
```

И, если нужно, то альгоритм вернет указатель на первый нечетный элемент.

Comment: А мы такие сложные штучки не прошли еще.

Comment: тогда пишите цикл

Comment: как ??? чтобы эффективно.

Comment: эффективно, понятие относительное_ почти всегда кто то напишет эффективнее. Вы сначала напишите как можете, а потом подумайте как улучшать. Таким образом вы быстрее  научитесь самостоятельно решать, чем получая готовый код. А вдруг у вас возникнет отличная идея, а чужой код может помешать вашей фантазии... Подсказка: вы можете четные числа записать в другой массив такого же размера, а потом в  исходный массив записать сначала эти числа, а потом остальные.

Comment: Нельзя использовать дополнительную память.